# Match a domain name to a SSL certificate in a local file

Tags: python, ssl, x509

I've got a bunch of SSL certificates in files on the local disk of a server, and want to find the right certificate for a given domain name.  Recent versions of Python provide the [`ssl.match_hostname()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.match_hostname) function which in principle is all that's needed.  However, it expects the certificate in a decoded Python dictionary format as returned by [`ssl.SSLSocket.getpeercert()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLSocket.getpeercert), and I can't find a way to parse a certificate from a local file into that format.  The underlying C function that performs the parsing does not seem to be exposed directly.

So how can I find the matching SSL certificate for a given hostname?  This does not seem like a completely exotic thing to do.

What I would like to avoid is to parse the subject field and the subjectAltName extension of the x509 certificate and implement the hostname matching code myself, since there is a certain complexity involved.  (The [relevant code in the Python standard library for the domain name matching part alone](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/ssl.py#l203) goes on for more than hundred lines.)

Comment: Try [this neat script](https://github.com/clintecker/python-peace-of-mind/blob/master/src/peace_of_mind/certificates.py)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yeah, I found this as well.  However, it also retrieves the certificates from the server instead of from a local file.

Comment: You sure? The example shows local file: `c = certificates.CertificateChecker(domain='www.barackobama.com', ca_certs='/blah/var/share/ca_certs.pem')`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid It loads the CA certs from local files, but retrieves the server certificate from the named server via the network.  This is what you want to do to validate a cert on the client side.  I want to find the right cert on the server side instead.